# Google Maps Android API utility library: Add a circle around the marker, when marker becomes visible

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am working on Android application which makes use of Google Maps and Google Maps Android API Utility Library. By making use of the utility library I got the clustered markers. But I want to show circle around the marker, when markers become visible.
Following is the code I am using to add clustered markers:

```
public class ClusterMarkersFragment {

public GoogleMap map;
private ClusterManager<MarkerItem> fenceClusterManager;

public static ClusterMarkersFragment newInstance () {
    ClusterMarkersFragment clusterMarkersFragment = new
        ClusterMarkersFragment();
    return clusterMarkersFragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_cluster_marker_map,
                                  container, false );

    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById( R.id.view_map )).getMap();
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(false);

    fenceClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MarkerItem>(getActivity(), map);

    map.setOnCameraChangeListener(fenceClusterManager);

    addClusterItems(getListofLatLngPairs());

    return view;
}

private List< LatLngPair > getListofLatLngPairs () {
     // returns the list from database
}   

private void addClusterItems(List<LatLngPair> latLngPairs) {
for (LatLngPair latLngPair : latLngPairs) {
    MarkerItem markerItem = new MarkerItem(latLngPair.lat, latLngPair.lng, (int) latLngPair);
    fenceClusterManager.addItem(markerItem);

}
}
}
```

Following are the screenshots

When Clustered 
[image]

When Cluster rendered current behavior
[image]
Desired Behavior
 [image]

Comment: can you elaborate further what you want? I can't understand...
Do you want to see a circle around the cluster or around the single markers when cluster is split up?

Comment: @N Dorigatti I want a marker to have circle around it when cluster is rendered. Or you can say in my code I want Each MarkerItem to have a circle around it's marker.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void addcircleAroundMarker() {
GoogleMap mapView;
    // circle settings  
    int radiusM = RADIUS OF CIRCLE;
    double latitude = CENTER LATITUDE;
    double longitude = CENTER LONGITUDE;
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);

    // draw circle
    // diameter 
    int d = 500; 
    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(d, d, Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bm);
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
    c.drawCircle(d/2, d/2, d/2, p);

    BitmapDescriptor bmD = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bm);

    mapView.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions().
            image(bmD).
            position(latLng,radiusM*2,radiusM*2).
            transparency(0.4f));
}
```

Comment: This won't work when we use Google Maps Android API Utility. It will keep the circles as it is on the map if we reform the cluster by zooming out. I already tried something similar to this